# Where can I find dependency identifiers of Spring Boot CLI?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using [Spring Boot CLI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-cli.html).

`spring help init` command says:

> -d, --dependencies
>
> Comma-separated list of dependency identifiers to include in the generated project

Where is "dependency identifiers" list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

spring init --list

The init command lets you create a new project by using start.spring.io without leaving the shell, as shown in the following example:

$ spring init --dependencies=web,data-jpa my-project

Refer here to get dependency list or you can directly generate project by selecting necessary dependencies from here https://start.spring.io